Bottles no session booked
System: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I have installed a Windows Program using Bottles. Its called Learnspace3D. Its a virtual Campus where you have an avatar, walk around and talk with other people. The Program starts normally. Then I have to login via a Button (Login via Browser with my .. account). The login works. I can open a Session then offline to explore the Campus (Free Exploration). That works fine. But normally there is a online Session booked for me. If I click on sessions. It says, there are currently no sessions booked for you. The server itself its written down in the program like https://3dwelt.....:443
If I am using a Windows VM, there is a session booked. But I just get 3 FPS. If I run the program on linux, its very fast and smooth. I just dont get the online session. What could the problem be there? What can I do to figure that out? Or what can I post that you get a deeper insight?
Thank you in advance!
